# In Deutsch's algorithm, why is $|x\rangle(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)$ mapped to $(-1)^{f(x)}|x\rangle(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I have just started to learn quantum computing, and my back ground is Computer Science. In Deutsch's Algorithm it is mentioned that the gate mapping $|x\rangle|y\rangle\mapsto |x\rangle|y+f(x)\rangle$, maps $|x\rangle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)$ to $(-1)^{f(x)}|x\rangle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)$.

Can anyone help me to see how this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within Deutsch's Algorithm, the function is defined $f:\left\{0,1\right\}\rightarrow\left\{0,1\right\}$. The gate mapping, which is given by the action of a unitary operator $\mathsf{U}_f$, is given by

$$\mathsf{U}_f|x\rangle|y\rangle=|x\rangle|y+f(x)\rangle$$

According to this, the action of this operator on your quantity of interest is

$$\mathsf{U}_f|x\rangle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)=|x\rangle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|f(x)\rangle-|1+f(x)\rangle)$$

Since $f(x)\in\left\{0,1\right\}$, then only two cases are possible. If $f(x)=0$, then

$$\mathsf{U}_{f}|x\rangle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)=|x\rangle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle-|1+0\rangle)=\underbrace{(-1)^{f(x)}}_{\displaystyle 1}|x\rangle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)\quad\mathrm{for}\,f(x)=0$$

Similarly, if $f(x)=1$, then

$$\mathsf{U}_{f}|x\rangle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)=|x\rangle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|1\rangle-\underbrace{|1+1\rangle}_{\displaystyle |0\rangle})=\underbrace{(-1)^{f(x)}}_{\displaystyle -1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)\quad\mathrm{for}\,f(x)=1$$